# Crystal report: How to suppress field depending upon next data field change?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How to suppress field depending upon next data field change?

I have datas (two colomns of a table) which is something like as below:

```
  SubItemcode___________IsLock

    SODBPCFBX01601G_______N

    SODBPCFBX01601G_______N

    SODRWFIMX01G017_______N

    SODRWFIMX01G017_______N 

    BG8Wx0191765044_______N

    BG8Wx0191765044_______N
```

to appeare on report as:

```
 IsLock________SubItemcode

    N_______SODBPCFBX01601G

    N_______SODBPCFBX01601G

    N_______SODRWFIMX01G017

    N_______SODRWFIMX01G017 

    N_______BG8Wx0191765044

    N_______BG8Wx0191765044
```

In report I set *SubItemcode* to suppress on dublication and same as for IsLock.

On which I get following output in report:

```
   IsLock________SubItemcode

        N_______SODBPCFBX01601G

        _______________________

        ________SODRWFIMX01G017

        _______________________ 

        ________BG8Wx0191765044

        _______________________
```

I want it like as below:

```
    IsLock________SubItemcode

        N_______SODBPCFBX01601G

        _______________________

        N_______SODRWFIMX01G017

        _______________________ 

        N_______BG8Wx0191765044

        _______________________
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are suppressing individual *fields* if the data in that field is duplicated. What you want to do is group your data.

1. Goto **Report->Group Expert**
2. Add the grouping field (in this case, probably `subitemcode`)
3. Move `IsLock` and `SubItemCode` to the Group Header section.
4. **Right-Click->Section Expert** to suppress the Details and Group Footer sections.

Comment: Thanks for bounty. However the group is not based on these columns. After doing these(as mention by you already) only I am getting the duplicate fields hidden. I already have grouped 'Details' based on 3 columns. Adding more is increasing the rows. Is that the reason for such issue? I m trying the way u mentioned.

Comment: I think the number of rows is increasing because you still have fields displayed in the Details section. If you move those to a group header, and suppress the Details section, your report should get smaller. (You can have as many groups as you need).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have your report in front of me so I can't understand your exact situation.  You'll have to work with it a little, but I'm sure it can be done.  Here's a tip: You can make a custom formula with "{IsLock}&{SubItemCode}" and then add an additional grouping by that custom formula.